# Разбор арифметического выражения в строке

Tags: php

Имеется строка формата `2a*3b+100` и 2 числа `a` и `b`.

Нужно разбить её на элементы и выполнить действия которые указаны в строке.
Хотел сделать через `miltiexplode(array("+","-","*","/"), $string)`, но в этом случае теряются знаки. 
Наверно, нужно перебрать по элементам, но я не вижу хорошего способа. Да и трудности испытываю со строками.

Comment: Эта задача не решается в лоб без готовой библиотеки, она на деревья или на стек, в зависимости от того, как вы будете осуществлять разбор. Тут скорее всего потребуется не только перебор, но и рекурсия. Самое просто с чего можно начать, это http://algolist.manual.ru/syntax/parsear.php

Answer (score 1):

`2a*3b` соответствует `2*a*3*b` т.е. поэтому explode не прокатит. тут можно покапать в сторону eval приводить строку к php подобной и выполнять к примеру

```
$formualPHP = '$a='.$youNamberA.';'; // это $a=2; 
$formualPHP .= '$b='.$youNamberB.';'; // это $b=3;
$formulaPHP .= 'return '.str_replace(array('a','b'),array('*$a','*$b'),$formula);
// $a=2;$b=3; return 2*$a*3*$b+100;
$result = eval($formulaPHP);  
var_dump($result);
```

**Но надо быть осторожным с eval() если числа могут быть пользовательськими т.е. взятые из get,post и д.р. источников.**

Comment: Кто то влепил минус и не отписался